# Repository xml file creation

Tags: xml, svn, svnkit

I want to create an xml file using SVNKit. We have already created the xml file using
`svn log --xml repourl` command-line, but to execute this command in Java I have used process. Its taking so long time. So I need to create the repository xml file using SVNKit or any other method.

Comment: I don't understand what you ask here. Have you tried to check the reference? http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/SVNLogClient.html